# AVSpeechSynthesizer speaker on

Tags: speaker, avspeechsynthesizer

I can hear the text read through my headphones when they are connected. However, if I disconnect headphones it doesn't play at all. How do I turn on speaker for this speech?
This is my code:

```
[syn stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
syn = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
syn.delegate = self;
utt = [AVSpeechUtterance  speechUtteranceWithString:rtext];
float speechSpeed = 0.3;
NSLog(@"Read***** text%@",rtext);
[utt setRate:speechSpeed];
utt.volume = 1;
[syn speakUtterance:utt];
```

Comment: My son help me to fix issue. My phone was in mode turn off ringing. This setup also turn off speaker for AVSpeechSynthesizer.